# PhoneGap Build Printing?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm building an app with HTML and JS, with JQuery Mobile and packaging with PhoneGap Build. Client wants to know if it's possible to add a print feature... Anyone know if it is? There's not PG Build print plugin so I'm not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no [core PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com) providing print support, and no [third party plugin](http://build.phonegap.com/plugins) providing print support on PhoneGap Build, the solution would have to be for someone to submit one to PhoneGap Build. It looks like the source for this solution exists out there (for [iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/PrintPlugin) and [Android](https://github.com/EionRobb/phonegap-print-plugins)). These code bases would need to be combined, updated and tested for the latest version of Cordova / PhoneGap. Here's an example of the source to [an active PhoneGap Build plugin](http://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a way to print using this amazing share plugin:
http://www.x-services.nl/phonegap-share-plugin-facebook-twitter-social-media/754

This way we can print (or email, message or even share to social media) the contents of a div.

Add the plugin to your config.xml file then call the function into the button using a variable:

```
<button type="button" onclick="var testPage = $('#myDiv').text(); window.plugins.socialsharing.share(testPage)">Share</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [plugin](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-print) to print, this plugin brings up a native overlay to print document, this plugin is using AirPrint for iOS and Google Cloud Print for android